# AutoIt PixelGetColor from background/inactive/unfocused window

Tags: background, autoit

[PixelGetColor](https://www.autoitscipt.com/autoit3/docs/functions/PixelGetColor.htm) has an optional parameter **hwnd** (handle of window the pixel is read from). Therefore I assume it is possible to read from unfocused windows (i.e not minimized, but behind another window); but I can't get it to work like that.

- Is my assumption wrong? If not, how would this be done? If so;

  - why the hwnd parameter?
  - is there another method involving pixel recognition?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible with it using the getdibits/getpixel it uses.  The hwnd is primarily used to make sure you're dealing within the client rect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Abstract

You want to create a simple empty bitmap and transfer the DeviceContext content of the hidden window into it. Then you can read any value at any position.

### Creating an empty bitmap

**Includes**

We will need to include the WinAPI definitions and constants.

```
#include <WinAPI.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
```

And that's about it.

**Initial struct**

Now we have to create a new DLL struct from the `$tagBITMAPINFO` template. We need to fill the struct with the bitmaps parameters. To ensure compatibility across all AutoIt version, I will access the struct items by index.

1) Create compatible Device Context:

```
Local $hCompDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC(0)
```

2) Create struct from template, fill with data:

```
Local $tBMI = DllStructCreate($tagBITMAPINFO)
DllStructSetData($tBMI, 1, DllStructGetSize($tBMI) - 4) ; size of struct
DllStructSetData($tBMI, 2, 400) ; width
DllStructSetData($tBMI, 3, 400) ; height
DllStructSetData($tBMI, 4, 1)
DllStructSetData($tBMI, 5, 32)  ; bits per pixel
```

You need to adjust the width and height parameters to match the region you want to transfer. In your case, I guess the size of the window would be a good choice, though the smaller the region, the faster.

3) Create GDI Object

Create a CreateDIBSection and save the important variables (object handle and struct pointer):

```
$aDIB = DllCall('gdi32.dll', 'ptr', 'CreateDIBSection', 'hwnd', 0, 'ptr', DllStructGetPtr($tBMI), 'uint', 0, 'ptr*', 0, 'ptr', 0, 'uint', 0)
$hGDIObj = $aDIB[0]
$hPtr = $aDIB[4]
```

4) Activate

Select the object to use it:

```
_WinAPI_SelectObject($hCompDC, $hGDIObj)
```

5) Create a pixel-map

This is a dword-array of color values. Replace 160000 with `width*height` of your region:

```
$hPixelStruct = DllStructCreate("dword[160000]", $hPtr)
```

### Capture window

Now we need to transfer the hidden window DeviceContext into our "virtual" context, but first the DC of the target (I'm using Paint as an example):

```
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("Paint")
$hWndDC = _WinAPI_GetDC($hWnd)
```

Let's transfer the DC into our DC, using PrintWindow:

```
Local $iX = 20 ; x coord of pixel in window DC (incl. title bar)
Local $iY = 20 ; y coord
DllCall("User32.dll", "int", "PrintWindow", "hwnd", $hWnd, "ptr", $hCompDC, "int", 0)
```

### Reading single pixels

Since `$hPixelStruct` is a continuous stream of values, we have to do a little bit of math to point at the right pixel:

```
$iColor = MsgBox(0, "Color", '0x' & Hex(DllStructGetData($hPixelStruct, 1, $iY * 400 + $iX + 1), 6))
```

### Cleaning up

Lastly, destroy the resources:

```
_WinAPI_ReleaseDC(0, $hCompDC)
_WinAPI_ReleaseDC($hWnd, $hWndDC)
```

### Results

Works perfectly. Though this is only valid for **hidden** windows, NOT minimized, as minimized windows do not have any drawn context.

[image: screenshot]

### Script

Here's a Gist containing the script: [minxomat/readcolor.au3](https://gist.github.com/minxomat/c03456a090a94e93e01b)